# Отсутствие перевода в новой шапке сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, приватный-режим

При открытии [главной страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) в приватном режиме наблюдается следующее:

> [image: нет перевода в шапке]

Как-то не солидно это. Надо бы перевести.

Comment: Выкатили перевод. Если будут другие предложения, всегда можно поправить)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12943

Предложил:

> $Name$ — это сайт вопросов и ответов для $Audience$. Присоединяйтесь! Регистрация займёт не больше минуты.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12944

Предложил:

> Присоединиться к сообществу

Comment: Сюда бы еще ссылок на вопросы с выбором "не больше/не займёт" и, возможно, кавычки вокруг имени сайта, тоже где-то было обсуждение. Пока на мобильном, не удобно искать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ люди могут свой вариант предложить в ответе. В традусёре я лишь предложение кинул (:

Comment: люди :) и не только

Comment: @αλεχολυτ про роботов забыл, каюсь (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @αλεχολυτ зелёная галочка ждёт     (¬ ¬ )

Comment: там сейчас другой косяк с "Explore our Questions"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [сюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).